# Angular html table ngfor for rows issue

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular8, angular-ngfor

I have this html for Angular:

```
<table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                            {{col}}
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th *ngFor="let col of subColumns">
                            {{col}}
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let priceRow of priceRows">
                    <td *ngFor="let price of priceRow">
                        {{price}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>    
            </table>
```

This is the content for priceRows for which I'm trying to do rows:

[image]

But I'm getting empty table when trying to print out the table.

Do you see anything wrong in the array for priceRows?

Stackblitz url: https://angular-bnxfca.stackblitz.io

Comment: Can you share it in stackbiltz or share all the json

Comment: https://angular-bnxfca.stackblitz.io @AdritaSharma

Comment: The shared url isn't working

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bnxfca please try this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TS:

```
priceRows: any[] = [];
```

Try this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{col}}
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of subColumns">
                {{col}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let price of priceRows">
            <td *ngFor="let item of price">
                {{item}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**[Working Stackbiltz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ka96zb?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Add validation through * ngIf (columns && subColumns && priceRows && priceRow) to tag table.

```
<table *ngIf="colums && subcolums...">
```

and validate Date on template

```
{{columns|json}}
{{subColumns |json}}
```

if data exist on template load, all will be fine